# Jquery mobile flickering issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

How to stop flickering of page while selecting menu from dropdown list in jQuery mobile with     Android?

I am using jQuery Mobile 1.2.0 and Cordova 2.0.0 and Android version is 2.3.4.

Comment: there are several issues with jqm but most of these are solved with android 4.0 and also with the latest JQM 1.2 launch. Android 2.1 - Android 3.0 has poor html5 performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used

```
$("#pageId").live('pageinit',function() {
$.mobile.defaultDialogTransition = "none";
$.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "none";});
```

and its working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add `-webkit-backface-visibility` as hidden.Like this:

```
 .ui-page {
   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
   }
```

And say goodnight to the dreaded Android flicker!

Comment: @snehad , where did you put this style..? you need to put it in a css file that loads after the jquerymobile.css file if using it..

Comment: @ A.V.I have placed like this <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/my.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/jqm-datebox.min.css" />
 <style>
  .ui-page {
      -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
     }
 </style>

Answer (score 0):

Here, I come with the solution........

Please follow the sequesnce

```
// load jQuery
script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

// load your custom jQuery Mobile Defaults
<script type="text/javascript" src="mobile/js/mobile-jqm.js"></script>

// load jQuery Mobile
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

// load your scripts.js (your javascript & functions, etc.)
<script type="text/javascript" src="mobile/js/script.js"></script>
```

To disable transitions, create mobile-jqm.js filt & inside of the mobile-jqm.js file, place this code:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
  $.extend(  $.mobile , {
   defaultPageTransition: 'none'
  });
});
```